# alertdialog lies below webview, so the user cannot see the alertdialog

Tags: webview, flutter, android-alertdialog

I have a simple webview app built with `flutter` and `flutter_webview_plugin` library. I am trying to add push notification with `firebase cloud messaging`. The push notification works fine when the app is running in background or is switched off. If the app is on, I configured such that it shows an `alert dialog`. But this part does not work.

I removed the `webview` widget and instead added an `appBar` widget then hot reloaded the app. `alert dialog` was actually there working fine. It seems like the `webview` layer is above the `alert dialog` layer. So even though `alert dialog` did pop out correctly, the user cannot see it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MyApp(),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();
  }

  void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print(token);
    });

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                content: ListTile(
                  title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
                  subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Ok'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        );
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: new WebviewScaffold(
            url: "https://m.url.co.kr",
            hidden: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first hide the webviewplugin using this line: webviewPlugin.hide(); and then run the code to create the alertdialog as such:

```
webviewPlugin.hide();
showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                content: ListTile(
                  title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
                  subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Ok'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the flutter_webview_plugin package, you have to switch to the offical [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) in order to do this...

The flutter_webview_plugin devs also give you this warning message:

*Warning: The webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a native view on top of the flutter view. you won't be able to use snackbars, dialogs ...*

Good luck

Comment: yea, I am aware of that issue. So prior to alert, I closed the webview. And this did work with the simulator